# mongoimport error - Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb, macos, database

I am currently trying to learn mongodb and I am having trouble finding a solution for this problem.
When I run a mongoimport command it I get the following error:

```
~ mongoimport --host localhost --port 27017 --db test --collection people --file ~/Downloads/mongodb-consultas.json --jsonArray
2015-09-27T20:46:03.228-0600    [........................] test.people  0.0 B/684.2 KB (0.0%)
2015-09-27T20:46:03.745-0600    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
2015-09-27T20:46:03.745-0600    imported 0 documents
```

I have a mongodb server by running `mongod` in the command line.

My MongoDB shell version is 3.0.6.

Thank you!

Comment: This indicates that either the server is no running or you have a firewall rule blocking access to the port. Most likely it is not actually running. Try basically connecting the `mongo` shell and check the running status of the server.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I am also running mongo, it shows "connecting to: test" and some other information. How can I determine if the firewall is blocking access to the port?

Comment: @BlakesSeven I just checked and the firewall allows incoming connections for mongod...

Comment: What happens if you use `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost? Furthermore, this question should have been asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg yeah that does not work either... I get the following error instead `Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format - found no opening bracket '[' in input source`. The file that I am trying to import is not corrupted as I got it from a tutorial. Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about dba.stackexchange.com. I will try asking for help there as well.

Comment: @German Its an either here **or** there thing. Basically, you have a connection now. Please add the output of `head -c20 yourfile.json` to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use --host 127.0.0.1:27017

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `--host localhost` to `--host 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

The `-h 127.0.0.1` parameter is a quick workaround, but upgrading to MongoDB 3.0.7 fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, mongo cluster is `ssl` enabled so I had a problem to connect mongo servers. I just add `--ssl` it works fine. It might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Old but since this doesn't have an answer yet:

I had the same issue and looked at all the questions and none contained the solution to my specific problem. I had created my user in the "admin" database, which I had to specify when calling mongoimport with the `--authenticationDatabase` argument. Can check all the arguments [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the an answer for those who are struggling with the same issue while using MongoDB Atlas.

I tried to follow the offical guides like [Seed with mongorestore](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongorestore/) and [Load File with mongoimport](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongoimport/) but received the same `no reachable servers` error.

I tried to change the command arguments over and over - nothing changed.

But then  **I navigated inside my cluster to the "Command Line Tools" tab and saw the exact command I should run** for `mongorestore`, `mongodump`, `mongoimport`,`mongoexport` etc':

[image]

Adding as inline the full command:

```
mongorestore --host 
<cluster-name>-shard-0/
<cluster-name>-shard-00-00-obe3i.mongodb.net:27017,
<cluster-name>-shard-00-01-obe3i.mongodb.net:27017,
<cluster-name>-shard-00-02-obe3i.mongodb.net:27017 
--ssl 
--username <User-Name> 
--password <PASSWORD> 
--authenticationDatabase admin
```

The `mongorestore` comand can be replaced with `mongodump`,`mongoimport`,`mongoexport` etc'.

(*) Prefer copying the command directly from dashboard because the DNS of the replica-sets might change.

(**) MongoDB shell version v4.2.5.